# GTM "Set as Latest Version" Alternatives

Tags: google-tag-manager

Is there any way to at least overwrite the recent version ID (version3) instead of Set as Latest Version? It seems that I can edit the recent version but in my previous versions I have the option to Delete them. If so, do you have any idea on when the "Delete" option can be available in my recent versions? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Because the new version your created has an error and you never want to use it?

Comment: Yes, the live versions have few errors and I would like to create a new version and would try to use exceptions, would that be okay? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Go edit this version or rollback to your previous version, do changes you want and than preview it, test it and publish it. This will create a new version and you will have no troubles at all.